# Marketing Cloud REST API - GET method to Data Extensions

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, dataextensions

I'm currently using the POST and PUT methods to add and modify rows in custom data extensions (as documented [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/postDataExtensionRowsetByKey.htm)) but i don't see anywhere on the documentation nor the stackexchange a GET method to get rows for a specific ID ?

Answer (score 17):

You'll have to use the SOAP API to [**retrieve DataExtensionObjects**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/retrieving_data_from_a_data_extension.htm).

Here's a sample envelope that illustrates the structure of the call:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Header>
        <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" soapenv:mustUnderstand="1">
            <wsse:UsernameToken xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="UsernameToken-24440876">
                <wsse:Username>XXXXX</wsse:Username>
                <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">XXXXX</wsse:Password>
            </wsse:UsernameToken>
        </wsse:Security>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
            <RetrieveRequest>
                <ObjectType>DataExtensionObject[EXTERNALKEYOFDE]</ObjectType>
                <Properties>EMAIL_ADDRESS</Properties>
                <Properties>CUSTOMER_ID</Properties>
                <Properties>FIRST_NAME</Properties>
                <Properties>SITE_GROUP</Properties>
                <Filter xsi:type="SimpleFilterPart">
                    <Property>EMAIL_ADDRESS</Property>
                    <SimpleOperator>equals</SimpleOperator>
                    <Value>test@example.com</Value>
                </Filter>
            </RetrieveRequest>
        </RetrieveRequestMsg>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

At this point in time, the SFMC SOAP API is significantly more complete/robust/whatever than the REST API. It's a good plan to follow the lead of the [**SFMC SDK**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-sdks.meta/mc-sdks/index-sdk.htm), which utilizes both SOAP and REST.

**2019-09-16 Update**

This is floating around the community in some comments, but I thought I'd update my answer to include the undocumented REST route for retrieving a Data Extension row. The filter is specified in the URL.

```
GET /data/v1/customobjectdata/key/YOURDEEXTERNALKEY/rowset?$filter=emailAddress%20eq%20'test@example.com' HTTP/1.1
Host: YOURTENANT.rest.marketingcloudapis.com
Authorization: Bearer YOURAUTHTOKEN
Content-Type: application/json
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.17.1
Accept: */*
Cache-Control: no-cache
Host: YOURTENANT.rest.marketingcloudapis.com
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
cache-control: no-cache
```

**Results**

```json
{
  "links": {
    "self": "/v1/customobjectdata/token/5f9c1ce3-8f0f-499c-a1dd-5a9bf6fbfa01/rowset?$page=1"
  },
  "requestToken": "71dac1af-88ed-48f1-bce2-259d2a1d5009",
  "tokenExpireDateUtc": "2019-09-17T18:48:03.03",
  "customObjectId": "9340eb5c-3a53-4490-a1f1-2d14c1b27c98",
  "customObjectKey": "YOURDEEXTERNALKEY",
  "pageSize": 2500,
  "page": 1,
  "count": 1,
  "items": [
    {
      "keys": {
        "emailAddress": "test@example.com"
      },
      "values": {
        "firstname": "Test",
        "lastname": "Person",
        "createddate": "7/18/2019 6:00:00 PM"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: With the Spring '24 Release this is finally supported!

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_rn_2024_spring_as_rest_api_endpoints.htm&type=5

Answer (score 6):

If you're Data Extension is included in an Attribute Group in Contact Builder, then you can use the [search REST API method](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/fetchAttributes.htm) to retrieve a value from one or more Data Extensions. For example, in this case I'm retrieving the First Name and Last name from a Contacts Data Extension based on a couple of criteria (from the Email address and a different Data Extension):

```js
POST https://www.exacttargetapis.com/contacts/v1/attributes/search
Authorization: Bearer insertAccessTokenHere
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "request": {
        "attributes": [
            {
                "key": "Contacts.First Name"
            },
            {
                "key": "Contacts.Last Name"
            }]

    },
    "conditionSet": {
        "operator": "And",
        "conditionSets": [],
        "conditions": [{
            "attribute": {
                "key": "Email Addresses.Email Address"
            },
            "operator": "Equals",
            "value": {
                "items": ["sam@sample.com"]
            }
        },
        {
            "attribute": {
                "key": "Centre Subscriptions.valid"
            },
            "operator": "Equals",
            "value": {
                "items": [true]
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this works if a Contact has not been added for the matching row in the Data Extension.  I've been testing this kind of retrieve and it didn't work for rows that had no Contact.

Comment: Hmm, I didn't try that scenario. Good to know!

Comment: It's so crazy that you can add a row to DE with REST but can't retrieve one.  Maybe I'm missing something in the documentation.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense now I come to think of it. This is based on the Contact Model, so it will only work for contacts. If you're not using Contacts, then you will have to use SOAP.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a Rest API v2 endpoint that can be used to retrieve data from data extension. I've also added some optional query parameters to filter data.

```js
GET https://{{et_subdomain}}.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/data/v1/customobjectdata/key/{{DataExtensionKey}}/rowset?$pageSize=20&$page=1&$filter={{columnName}}%20eq%20'{{value}}'
Authorization: Bearer {{access_token}}
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "links": {
      "self": "/v1/customobjectdata/token/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxxxxxxxxx/rowset?$page=1"
  },
  "requestToken": "{{request-token}}",
  "tokenExpireDateUtc": "2023-02-02T13:49:42.117",
  "customObjectId": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxxxxxxxxx",
  "customObjectKey": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxxxxxxxxx",
  "pageSize": 20,
  "page": 1,
  "count": 1,
  "top": 0,
  "items": [
      {
          "keys": {
              "id": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxxxxxxxxx"
          },
          "values": {
              "title": "Candy",
              "link": "https://www.google.com/",
              "price": "0.99 USD",
              "brand": "ABC",
              "image_link": "https://www.w3schools.com/html/img_girl.jpg",
              "availability": "in stock"
          }
      }
  ]
}
```

Docs

```js
GET https://{{et_subdomain}}.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/data/v1/rest
```