# Updating records That entered the journey and getting the updated values with Custom Activity

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I have a journey Where in user will enter 2 of the same custom activities

[image]

**Happening Right Now**

User enters custom activity 1 and sends product information to a webservice to get a product quotation now during the waiting period, the product information was updated manually or through api, Now users enter custom activity 2, even though the product information was updated in the waiting period. It still sends the old product information to the webservice thus receiving an old quotation.

**Correct Scenario**

User enters custom activity 1 and sends product information to a webservice to get a product quotation now during the waiting period, the product information was updated, the product information update can either be done manually or through api. Now once the user enters custom activity 2 it sends the updated product information to a webservice to receive an updated quotation.

**What i need is to be able to get the updated information of the user in the journey.**

I use parseEventSchema to get the columns of the data extension and use payload to pass the bindings to my inarguments in my config.json.

Now in my execute function, I can get the data of the user that entered the journey.

**Sample Data Extension Column**

```
PrimaryKey
CampaignMemberId
Product Name
Product Quantity
Product Group
```

This is what my execute method in custom activity looks like

```
    console.log("EXECUTE HAS BEEN RUN");
JWT(req.body, process.env.JWT_KEY, (err, decoded) => {

    // verification error -> unauthorized request
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        return res.status(401).end();
    }


    if (decoded && decoded.inArguments && decoded.inArguments.length > 0) {[]

    //Use fields in decoded.inarguments to create a request body
    //use node.js to do webservice
    //decoded args contains the data to get the token and do a marketing 
    //cloud rest api call
    var bodyStringAdvertising = JSON.stringify({
    //Sample body
    })

    var headersAdvertising = {
    //Sample header
    }

    var optionsAdvertising = { 
    method: 'POST',
    headers: headersAdvertising,
    url: '//Sample URL'
    };

    request(optionsAdvertising, function (error, response, body) {
    if (error) throw new Error(error);
    console.log('response body',body);

    //Once I get the response, I'm going to use some of the values to update 
    a row in a Data Extension
    //How Can I do that

    }).write(bodyStringAdvertising); 

    } else {
        console.error('inArguments invalid.');
        return res.status(400).end();
    }

});

console.log("end execute function!!!");
```

Comment: Hi imajmdf. Are the product values being updated into a DE in Salesforce Marketing Cloud? Is the Product DE connected to the customer via the Contact Builder relationships?

Comment: Hi @CameronRobert The product values are already in DE, I'm just trying to update for example a name row, from 'testing product' to 'new product' and I don't think that the DE is connected to the customer via the Contact Builder Relationship. Can this be fixed if I connect the DE to the customer? Thanks!

Comment: Can you update your question to include examples of the data extensions and an example of what you want the final result to look like? Understanding this will help to solve your question. Does this need to happen in Journey Builder, or could it be done in SSJS/SQL/etc?

Comment: @CameronRobert i updated the question, there's an expected scenario and current scenario. Thank you

Comment: @CameronRobert the end use of custom activity is to send a request to a webservice, my only issue is even though I updated the user data while he's in the journey, I'm still getting old values once it enters custom activity 2

Comment: Thanks for updating the question - I think I understand what you are trying to achieve. When you reference data in a Journey, it uses the "Journey Data" as it was on entry. So even through your API/Manual update is changing values, Journey Builder has kept the original values and is using those. Your custom activity 1 & 2, are they referencing data stored in a Data Extension or the Journey Data?

Comment: @CameronRobert. They're both referencing journey data. I also tried looking for api calls to get the data stored in data extension but unfortunately I can only find  upsert api calls. Is there any way that I can get data stored in data extension using api and use it in my execute method? Thanks a lot for the help

Comment: Happy to help @imajmdf. What language are you using for the custom activity/API?

Comment: I use node.js for my api calls. I'll update the question for the pseudo code  of my execute method in custom activity.

Comment: The product information that is being retrieved by the API-POST call (and being updated into a Data Extension), can you confirm that the update is happening; you've checked the data in the DE? How is the data being used? There is no Email activity in the Journey above. Is there another journey/triggered activity taking place? Assuming this activity happens in Marketing Cloud - is it possible to conduct a LookupRows() (or similar) in AMPScript to ensure the email is referencing the correct DE, and not the Journey's entry data?

Comment: I'm sure that the update is happening because when I deactivate the journey and activate it again. Once the user enters custom activity 1 it returns the updated value. This journey is just used to do a request to a webservice and use the response data. No email activity is happening. For the api call to update data i used this api call https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/postDataExtensionRowsetByKey.htm

Comment: Ok, that narrows down the issue. Can you confirm what data source is being used in Activity 2; how are you retrieving the data that is used in activity #2 to send to the webservice? Are you using SSJS or the REST API (via Node.js)?

Comment: Well actually activity 2 and activity 1 are the same. I use rest api via node js. I use parseEventScema to pass journey fields to my inArguments(config.json) so that I can get the values in my execute method @cameronrobert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on our conversation so far, I believe the issue you're having is the difference between Journey and Contact data.
[image]

You can read more here: [Journey vs Contact Data](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_journey_contact_data.htm&type=5)
Demo use case here: [Journey and Contact Data in Decision Splits](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_journey_contact_data_decision_splits.htm&type=5)

I believe you could solve your issues by changing your custom activities to lookup Contact Data, rather than the Journey data. Adam Spriggs recently updated a ticket on how to do this using the REST API here: [GET method to Data Extensions](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/152409/marketing-cloud-rest-api-get-method-to-data-extensions)

Comment: thanks a lot! I'll look this up!