# Dependent dropdowns in Cloudpages and Dropdown values to be pulled dynamically from a DE without page refresh!

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I have a cloud page set up as below.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ltqT9.png

And **2 Data Extensions** as below,
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2P75P.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/3BRh9.png

I need to achieve the below,
1) Both the drop down values to be pulled from respective DE.
2) The Category drop down should be populated **based on the value selected in Gender** drop-down.As below,
If I Select MALE, it must pull ONLY Male categories from DE
https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKFSZ.png

Currently I have achieved this via blend of JS and AMPscript, but is there any efficient way. 
I know there there is NO REST-API to pull DE rows.
Also we can use a simple AMPscript LookupRows, but this will make a page refresh!

Any different approaches are welcome!

Current code

```js
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>E-commerce_KT_demo_product Details page</title>
<style type="text/css">
#Gender_div { width: 300px; height: 50px; text-align: right; left: 100px; position: relative; }
#Category_div { width: 300px; height: 50px; text-align: right; left: 100px; position: relative; }
</style>
</head>
<body style="height:auto; overflow:visible;">
<h1 style="color:maroon; text-align:center;">Product Details Page</h1>
<div id="Gender_div">
    %%[
    var @Gender_rows, @Gender_row, @rowCount, @i
    set @Gender_rows = LookupRows("Gender_DE", "default", "1")
    set @rowCount = rowcount(@Gender_rows)
    if @rowCount > 0 then 
        for @i = 1 to @rowCount do
            if @i == 1 then
              output(concat('Select Gender:  ','<select name="Gender" onchange="javascript: dynamicdropdown(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);" ><option value="">Select</option>'))
            endif
            var @Gender
            set @Gender_row = row(@Gender_rows, @i)
            set @Gender = field(@Gender_row,"Gender")
            output(concat('<option value="', @Gender, '">', @Gender, '</option>'))
            if @i == @rowCount then
              output(concat('</select>'))
            endif
        next @i 
    else
     output(concat("<br>companies not found"))
    endif 
    ]%%
</div>
<div id="Category_div">
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            function dynamicdropdown(listindex)
            {
                document.getElementById("Category").length = 0;
                switch (listindex)
                {
                    case "Male" :
                        document.getElementById("Category").options[0]=new Option("Male Categories","Male Categories");
                        document.getElementById("Category").options[3]=new Option("Jackets","Jackets");
                        document.getElementById("Category").options[4]=new Option("Jeans","Jeans");
                        document.getElementById("Category").options[5]=new Option("Shorts","Shorts");
                        document.getElementById("Category").options[2]=new Option("Boots","Boots");
                        break;
                    case "Female" :
                        document.getElementById("Category").options[0]=new Option("Female Categories","Female Categories");
                        document.getElementById("Category").options[3]=new Option("Tops","Tops");
                        document.getElementById("Category").options[4]=new Option("Jeggings","Jeggings");
                        document.getElementById("Category").options[5]=new Option("Skirts","Skirts");
                        document.getElementById("Category").options[2]=new Option("Sandles","Sandles");
                        break;
                }
                return true;
            }
       </script>
    %%[
    var @Category_rows, @Category_row, @rowCount, @i
    set @Category_rows = LookupRows("Category", "default", "1")
    set @rowCount = rowcount(@Category_rows)
    if @rowCount > 0 then 
        for @i = 1 to @rowCount do
            if @i == 1 then
              output(concat('Select Category:  ','<select id="Category" name="Category"><option value="">Select Gender first</option></select>'))
            endif
        next @i 
    else
     output(concat("<br/>Categories not found"))
    endif 
    ]%%
</div>
</body>
</html>


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFz1S.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYOh0.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYMiu.png
  [4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rejYR.png
  [5]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QomHr.png
```

Answer (score 1):

You can build a code-resource CloudPage that returns a JSON payload for your AJAX call.

Here's a server-side JavaScript example that reads `state` and `store` URL parameter values from the origin page and retrieves data up to 100 rows from a `Master_Store` data extension.

```
<script type="text/javascript" runat="server">

  Platform.Load("core", "1");
  var state = Request.GetQueryStringParameter("state");
  var store = Request.GetQueryStringParameter("store");
  var storeDE = DataExtension.Init("Master_Store");
  var locations = (state) ? storeDE.Rows.Lookup(["state"], [state], 100, "city") : storeDE.Rows.Lookup(["store"], [store], 100);
  locations = locations ? locations : "";
  Write('{"Locations":' + Stringify(locations) + '}');

</script>
```

There is [an undocumented REST endpoint to retrieve data extension rows](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/152415/5202), but you don't need it if you just build your own code resource page.